# Design pattern for use case

Tags: java, design-patterns, uml

I wonder how to model this:

There are medical tests, such tests have a name, description, and may have one or more components.

Each component has a maximum value and a minimum reference value.

Example, blood pressure is a test, and consists with systolic blood pressure and diastolic blood pressure.

There are also patients that perform these tests.

The form of modeling that comes to my mind is this, but it does not convince me.
[image]

Comment: The title is a bit misleading. Shouldn't it be something like "How to model ..."?

Comment: Are "systolic blood pressure" and "diastolic blood pressure" components? I'm not sure I understand the sentence correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use Factory Pattern. What is in my mind is: MedicalTest is an interface. SystolicTest and DiastolicTest implements MedicalTest. There will be MedicalTestFactory to generate the Test base on the information. It depends on your requirements, you can combine with other patterns. For the detail you can refer: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

This is what comes to my mind:

[image]

MedicalTest is an abstract class. BloodPressureTest inherits from MedicalTest.